# jquery fadeIn and fadeOut not working before click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have one form like this.

```
<form method="post" action="contact-post.php" id="contact_form" name="contactForm">
                     <div class="left_form">
                        <div>
                            <span><label>NAME</label></span>
                            <div id='name_error' class='error' style="background-color:#FFBCBB;text-align:center;margin-bottom:5px;">Please enter your name.</div>
                            <span><input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="textbox"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span><label>E-MAIL</label></span>
                            <div id='email_error' class='error' style="background-color:#FFBCBB;text-align:center;margin-bottom:5px;">Please enter your name.</div>
                            <span><input name="email" id="email" type="text" class="textbox" required></span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span><label>PHONE</label></span>
                            <div id='phone_error' class='error' style="background-color:#FFBCBB;text-align:center;margin-bottom:5px;">Please enter your name.</div>
                            <span><input name="phone" id="phone" type="text" class="textbox"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right_form">
                        <div>                           
                            <span><label>SUBJECT</label></span>
                            <div id='message_error' class='error' style="background-color:#FFBCBB;text-align:center;margin-bottom:5px;">Please enter your name.</div>
                            <span><textarea name="message" id="message" required> </textarea></span>
                        </div>
                        <div id='mail_success' class='success' style="background-color:#BFD6BF;text-align:center;margin-bottom:5px;">Your message has been sent successfully.</div>
                        <div id='mail_fail' class='error' style="background-color:#FFBCBB;text-align:center;margin-bottom:5px;">Sorry, error occured this time sending your message.</div>
                        <div id="submit">
                            <span><input type="submit" id="send_message" name="submit" value="Submit" class="myButton"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </form>
```

and i call one .js file for it is.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#send_message').click(function(e){

        //Stop form submission & check the validation
        e.preventDefault();

        // Variable declaration
        var error = false;
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var subject = $('#phone').val();
        var message = $('#message').val();

        // Form field validation
        if(name.length == 0){
            var error = true;
            $('#name_error').fadeIn(500);
        }else{
            $('#name_error').fadeOut(500);
        }
        if(email.length == 0 || email.indexOf('@') == '-1'){
            var error = true;
            $('#email_error').fadeIn(500);
        }else{
            $('#email_error').fadeOut(500);
        }
        if(subject.length == 0){
            var error = true;
            $('#phone_error').fadeIn(500);
        }else{
            $('#phone_error').fadeOut(500);
        }
        if(message.length == 0){
            var error = true;
            $('#message_error').fadeIn(500);
        }else{
            $('#message_error').fadeOut(500);
        }

        // If there is no validation error, next to process the mail function
        if(error == false){
           // Disable submit button just after the form processed 1st time successfully.
            $('#send_message').attr({'disabled' : 'true', 'value' : 'Sending...' });

            /* Post Ajax function of jQuery to get all the data from the submission of the form as soon as the form sends the values to email.php*/
            $.post("contact-post.php", $("#contact_form").serialize(),function(result){
                //Check the result set from email.php file.
                if(result == 'sent'){
                    //If the email is sent successfully, remove the submit button
                     $('#submit').remove();
                    //Display the success message
                    $('#mail_success').fadeIn(500);
                }else{
                    //Display the error message
                    $('#mail_fail').fadeIn(500);
                    // Enable the submit button again
                    $('#send_message').removeAttr('disabled').attr('value', 'Send The Message');
                }
            });
        }
    });    
});
```

and one contact-post.php file is.

```
<?php
include('config.php');
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$name=$_POST['name'];
$mail=$_POST['email'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$msg=$_POST['message'];
function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}
test_input($name);
$query="INSERT INTO `inquiry` (id,name,contact,email,query) values ('','$name','$phone','$mail','$msg')";
$qur=mysql_query($query);
    if ($qur) {
        echo 'sent';
    }
    else {
        echo 'failed';
    }
}
?>
```

my problem is when i refresh page it's displaying like this.

[image]

i want that all message should not display before clicking submit button.please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update (adding snippet) :

```css
.error , .success
{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="contact-post.php" id="contact_form" name="contactForm">
                     <div class="left_form">
                        <div>
                            <span><label>NAME</label></span>
                            <div id='name_error' class='error' style="background-color:#FFBCBB;text-align:center;margin-bottom:5px;">Please enter your name.</div>
                            <span><input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="textbox"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span><label>E-MAIL</label></span>
                            <div id='email_error' class='error' style="background-color:#FFBCBB;text-align:center;margin-bottom:5px;">Please enter your name.</div>
                            <span><input name="email" id="email" type="text" class="textbox" required></span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span><label>PHONE</label></span>
                            <div id='phone_error' class='error' style="background-color:#FFBCBB;text-align:center;margin-bottom:5px;">Please enter your name.</div>
                            <span><input name="phone" id="phone" type="text" class="textbox"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right_form">
                        <div>                           
                            <span><label>SUBJECT</label></span>
                            <div id='message_error' class='error' style="background-color:#FFBCBB;text-align:center;margin-bottom:5px;">Please enter your name.</div>
                            <span><textarea name="message" id="message" required> </textarea></span>
                        </div>
                        <div id='mail_success' class='success' style="background-color:#BFD6BF;text-align:center;margin-bottom:5px;">Your message has been sent successfully.</div>
                        <div id='mail_fail' class='error' style="background-color:#FFBCBB;text-align:center;margin-bottom:5px;">Sorry, error occured this time sending your message.</div>
                        <div id="submit">
                            <span><input type="submit" id="send_message" name="submit" value="Submit" class="myButton"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </form>
```

You can do one of the following :

Set the `error` and `success` classes display to none, since they will be displayed using the fadeIn function.

```
.error , .success
{
    display:none;
}
```

**Or**

You can hide the `<div>`s with jQuery on load as follows :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.error , .success').hide();

    ..... 
});
```

I guess the first solution would be a better approach since the elements will not view at all since CSS loads before JS (assuming that this is the order you are loading your files with), while in the second approach the elements will be visible until jQuery loads and hides them.

Comment: I have added a snippet, make sure that nothing else acts on these elements through CSS and overrides what you are trying to set.

Answer (score 0):

Add a style as below to hide the error/success messages.

```
#mail_fail, #mail_success{
display : none;
}
```